# Flutter: Android "network-security-config"

Tags: android, flutter, android-network-security-config

I have setup following to test the Flutter's network security based on the [Android document](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#additional-resources-codelabs) in order to implement **Certificate Pinning:**

Note that I specified the `domain-config` for `api.somesite.com`. So the app should only accept `somesite.com` certificate.

Note that `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` is set in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

In order to test the pinning certificate, I have two HTTP calls to two endpoints. One is from `api.somesite.com` and another is a random api.

However, both API endpoints work using the network security setting.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and why following the Android document for pinning certificate doesn't seem to have any effect on flutter itself.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you are using network_security_config.xml for using http website in your app?

Comment: I updated my question to be more clear. So, following the Android document, I have specified `domain` config with the pin certificates, meaning, the network should only be connected to the `api.somesite.com` as this is the one specified. However, when I test API calls with `api.somesite.com` and another random one (which should not work), works.. I am a bit lost to how to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article:
[Fix Cleartext Traffic Error in Android 9 Pie](https://medium.com/@son.rommer/fix-cleartext-traffic-error-in-android-9-pie-2f4e9e2235e6)

You may have as much domains as you need inside domain-config:

```
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">somesite.com</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">somesite2.com</domain>
</domain-config>
```

Don't add the domain with the "api." part.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Flutter does not consult the `android:networkSecurityConfig` attribute by default. Fortunately, you can configure it to do so by adding one more small element to your manifest, according to this page of the Flutter docs:
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/network-policy-ios-android#migration-guide

> For Flutter to find your XML file, you need to also add a `metadata` entry to the `<application>` tag in your manifest. This metadata entry should carry the name: `io.flutter.network-policy` and should contain the resource identifier of the XML.
>
> For instance, if you put your XML configuration under `res/xml/network_security_config.xml`, your manifest would contain the following:
>
> ```xml
> <application ...>
>   ...
>   <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.network-policy"
>              android:resource="@xml/network_security_config"/> </application>
> ```